# Login process using Reactjs, Axios and local JSON file

Tags: json, reactjs, redux, react-redux

This is a theoric question. Recently I started to work on React, which is a new area for me. I am trying to create a nice and educative frontend project.

Since it is a pure frontend project, I am using local json data. But I want my project to resemble real life projects as much as it is possible.

My question is, how should I keep the password? I copied fakestoreapi users section, so user passwosds are as it is, not encrypted at all. I can access them easily and I can see them.

I didn't use any kind of encryption yet. Should I? If I don't engage myself with backend, how to do that?

If no encryption involved in a frontend project, would that be so bad?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be storing the password encrypted with sha, just storing the plain password is dangerous and if you make any sort of mistake your user passwords would be available to someone.  If it's stored encrypted then even if they manage to get their hands on the passwords they'd still need to brute force it which is very unlikely.

One of the best and most commonly used libraries can be found here https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/.  This makes it easy to encrypt passwords using a simple line like:

```
var hash = crypto.SHA1('password');
```

Then you want to store that sha string as the user's password.  After that when the user logs in, you'll need to encrypt that password on the login and then compare the sha strings to make sure they're the same.  So you never store or work with the actual passwords, instead you store the sha (encrypted password) and the next time they log in you encrypt the password they've just entered on the login and you compare that with the old saved sha string you previously stored.  If those are the same then it means they typed in the same password again.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I was wondering, is SHA1 hashing best way to do this? Isn't bcrypt better or some other thing?

Comment: I'm not sure, bcrypt seems better for passwords, but you can look at the crypto documentation yourself to see what algorithm you want to use.